# Suppress Texmaker pre determined autocompletion

Tags: editors, auto-completion

I have tried pretty much all Latex editors out there, and I find Texmaker the best compromise between features and simplicity. However, I am quite annoyed that it is not possible to remove certain pre determined auto-complete suggestions. Anyone knows how to do that?

For instance, when I type "\begin{" the editor suggests a tons of autocompletion that I am never ever gonna use in my life, and I would really like to not have them there.

Answer (score 1):

Close texmaker, find the "texmaker.ini" file and change the value of 'Editor\Completion' from true to false and you are done.

On my system, the texmaker.ini file is in a hidden directory named '.config/xm1/texmaker.ini' inside my home directory.